# C# comparing two codes with foreach performance consideration

Tags: c#, performance, loops, sql-server-2019

I have a function like this

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.None,
                                        SystemDataAccess = SystemDataAccessKind.None,
                                        IsDeterministic = true,
                                        IsPrecise = true)]
    public static SqlInt16 func(
                                [SqlFacet(MaxSize = 1750)] SqlString cB,
                                [SqlFacet(MaxSize = 760)] SqlString sC
                               )
{
foreach (string code_div in cB.Value.Split('/'))
                {
                    cnt = (code_div.Length - code_div.Replace("+", string.Empty).Length) - (code_div.Length - code_div.Replace("+-", string.Empty).Length) / 2;
                    bool flag = true;
                    foreach (string code_plus in code_div.Split(new[] { '+' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                    {
                        if (code_plus[0] == '-')
                        {
                            if ((',' + sC.Value + ',').IndexOf(',' + code_plus.Substring(1) + ',') != -1)
                            {
                                flag = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if ((',' + sC.Value + ',').IndexOf(',' + code_plus + ',') == -1)
                            {
                                flag = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (flag)
                    {
                        return (SqlInt16)cnt;
                    }
                }
                return (SqlInt16)(-1);
            }
```

Here the '/' is an OR, a '+' an AND and '-' is NOT.
I need to return the first part of the code with 'flag = true' and the count of occurrences of the '+' minus the count of occurrences of '+-'.

This function is a sqlclr for SQL Server 2019 and I'm calling it some billion times.

The strings would look like this

```
    sC = "021A,775U,000A,021A,1U2,206B,240,249,255B,260,263B,280,294,2U1,306B,336B,345,427,440,442,474,477,4U4,500,508,523,543L,580,584,58U,5XXL,600,608,622,677,690,775U,802,831,909,928,953,966,99N,A20,A62,A66,A86,A89,B03,B09,B12,F204,FW,G996,GA,H80,HA,J82,K11,K13,L,M013,M22,M651,P49,R01,R75,U01,U18,U41,V22,VL,VR";

    //func returns 2
    cB = "+240+802/+240+803";

    //func returns 2
    cB = "-772+240+802/-P55+240+802/-772+240+803/-P55+240+803/-772+240+804/-P55+240+804/-772+240+805/-P55+240+805/-772+240+806/-P55+240+806";

    //func returns -1
    cB = "+-220+-299+-301+-355+-409+-518+-537+-540+-551+-810+-873+-889+-950+808";
```

I need some advice whether it is possible to optimize this function in regards of execution time, since it runs quite for a while.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Don't use such code in the first place. This is slow code on the client, because it generates temporary strings on every string operation. If this is called 1Bn times it will generate several billion string objects that have to be garbage-collected. It's far worse on the server because it steals CPU and RAM from the database engine

Comment: Instead of trying to parse unchanging text every time you want to query it, parse it *before* you load the data into the database and store it in proper tables with proper relations. If these strings have a specific format, find or create a parser for that format. Since you use SQL Server 2019 you can use Python scripts to parse the text. Numpy and Pandas are far faster than the loops in this code

Comment: PS: What is this method supposed to do in the first place? Why not use `STRING_SPLIT` to split `sC` and store it in a table? If that comes from the client ... why send it to the server? If there's a valid reason you could pass it as a Table Valued Parameter. As for the `cB` expression, it would be better if you actually used `AND` and `OR`. At least in Python you can use `eval` to evaluate expressions against data.

Comment: I'm receiving data like this and unfortunatelly has to process is like that... Splitting sC to an array took longer than searching the string

Comment: Process it *before* inserting the data into the database. Otherwise there's no point in using a database at all. Not only do you gain nothing, you're actually slowing down both your code and the database

Comment: `Splitting sC to an array took longer than searching the string` The code you posted splits strings all the time. Strings are immutable so every string operation generates temporary strings. `cB.Value.Split('/')` generates one new string for every part in the original string. So does every call to `code_div.Replace` and `code_div.Split`. `',' + sC.Value + ','` creates *two* temporary strings, one for each concatenation.

Comment: If you insist on using SQLCLR and that particular mini-language a) it will be slower than using Python and `sp_execute_external_script` with a better mini-language and b) you can get orders of magnitude better performance by using Regex so you don't have to split or concatenate anything. `.IndexOf` will always be slow because it doesn't take advantage of indexes - which is the whole point of using a database.